# Lifecycle of a PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have googled but I have not found an equivalent flowchart showing the life cycle of PreferenceActivities in android.  Does such a flowchart exist?  The one showing basic activity lifecycle was a big help getting to understand how activities work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PreferenceActivity` class extends the `Activity` class¹, hence the same lifecycle applies.

A PreferenceActivity just does some things for you in the relevant lifecycle methods, see [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java). Since you have to call the relevant superclass methods anyway, there isn't any major difference *(e.g. you have to call `super.onPause()` when you override `onPause()`)*.

¹ *it extends a ListActivity, which then extends the Activity class*

Comment: thanks for the info.  I was hoping to use this info to get an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653095/change-listpreference-title-programmatically.  Looks like I need to keep looking....